# Why is it suggested to keep 2cm between the chip and the remote antenna in TESEO-LIV3F?

Tags: rf, pcb-design, routing

I am reading the [TESEO-LIV3F hardware reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00399112-teseoliv3-gnss-module--hardware-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

In the remote antenna subsection (9.3, page 24), it explicitly suggest to keep a couple of centimeters between the chip and the remote antenna.

I am curious to understand the reason behind this recommendation, I always thought that the RF-track should be kept as short as possible. In my case I have a direct track going from the chip to an SMA connector.

Do you have other good recommendations about RF tracks routing?

Answer (score 0):

1. that is an exceptionally low-quality section of a manual for such a large and reputable manufacturer. ST should really re-write the manual.
2. What they probably mean is "if you have an external antenna, you do that, because you want to have an antenna that's better than what you have could mount on the PCB itself. So, don't mount that antenna so close to the PCB that it couples back into the PCB, that would be stupid.

Or, maybe not. The whole chapter is badly written, hand-wavy non-specific anecdotal information.

Comment: So basically it's a good idea to keep the SMA connector at 2cm from the chip, to limit coupling?

Comment: The verbatim wording is "*The best performance can be obtained if the remote antenna is placed more than 2cm far from Teseo-LIV3.*" (which is non-generalizable bullshit), and they say the *antenna* should be > 2cm away, not the connector.

Comment: Again, it really makes little sense to try and interpret too much into this document - the author of these texts doesn't sound like he has as much an idea of how things work as you do!

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! To be honest it is my first pcb that uses impedance matching and works above the GHz range, so I am not really confident with the choices I'm making, I just read the datasheets and other online resources and try to understand what is the best way to do it.